# find first index in array value greater than x in O(1)

Tags: java, arrays

I have a sorted array of type int. I want get the first index whose value is greater than a target in O(1), in java.

eg: int arr[]= {1,4,7,9,15,30}
target= 10
my function should return 4,index of 15.

Comment: *"in O(1)"* good luck with that. Since you don't know where you desired value is, you have to search for it and therefore *"n"* is important here.

Comment: I dont think this is possibly in O(1) Why do you need it done in O(1) it would be easy in O(n) though

Comment: It's sorted so you should be able to do better than O(n).

Comment: @Tom if you have a lookup table big enough, all problems are O(1) :-p

Comment: This is actually interesting and might be quite possible. However, I think you will have to give up something in order to be able to make a query like that. What I mean is, you will have to write a function in which inserting values into the array probably takes O(n), and maybe use extra space and then get a query which runs in O(1). I will see if I can come up with something

Answer (score 6):

In order to be able to find the index of a value that has a specific property (ex: is greater than a target) through an array, you must traverse the array implementing search algorithms.

**Therefore O(1) is not possible to achieve.**

- If the array is sorted, as you present it in your example, you are able to achieve what you want in O(log(n)) by implementing binary search algorithm. You may also use the implementation in [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-).
- If the array is not sorted, you must go through all the elements of the array in a worst case scenario using linear search algorithm with an O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

If you prepare an indices array (or map) like this.

```
    int[] a = {1,4,7,9,15,30};
    // prepare indices array
    int[] indices = new int[a[a.length - 1] + 1];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, aLength = a.length; i < aLength; ++i)
        while (j <= a[i])
            indices[j++] = i;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices));
    // -> [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
    // get the first index whose value is greater than a target in O(1)
    System.out.println(indices[10]); // -> 4 (index of 15)
```

You can get the index value by `indices[target]` in O(1).